# Calculating tangented lines to four spheres

Tags: geometry

We are given 4 points in space: $(0,0,0)$, $(a_2,0,0)$, $(a_3,b_3,0)$, $(a_4,b_4,c_4)$. Find all real tangented lines to spheres with radius $r$ ($r^2=R$). There are a maximum of 12 real tangented lines. Line is defined by point $(x,y,z)$ nearest to the origin on the sought line and the unit length tangent $(u,v,w)$ of the line. So, we have 6 equations (4 equations of sphere and 2 of line) and 6 variables $(x,y,z,u,v,w)$:

System of equations:
\begin{align}
&x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - R = 0 \\
&(a_2-x)^2 + y^2 + z^2 - (a_2u)^2 - R = 0 \\
&(a_3-x)^2 + (b_3-y)^2 + z^2 - (a_3u+b_3v)^2 - R = 0 \\
&(a_4-x)^2 + (b_4-y)^2 + (c_4-z)^2 - (a_4u+b_4v+c_4w)^2 - R = 0 \\
&xu + yv + zw = 0 \\
&u^2 + v^2 + w^2 - 1 = 0
\end{align}

I tried an algebraic approach, but at the start of the process I found that there would be a 16 equations with one variable of high degree.

Can anyone provide any better approach to finding all (12) real solutions to the system?

There are some articles that are connected to this problem but do not solve the following system:

[Common Tangents to Four Unit Balls in R3](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s004540010090)

[Lines Avoiding Unit Balls in Three Dimensions](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-005-1166-2)